# Notepad++ php load error page

Tags: php, load, notepad++

I have made a custom theme with wordpress locally with wamp.I use notepad++ for writing my code.Some days before when I wanted to load my page from notepad I had to go to run->launch in Firefox and had no problem showing the page where in the address bar the URL was:localhost/wordpress.

Now when I try to load my php files from notepad (run ->launch in Firefox) it shows a corrupt html page not all of it ,with some rules of php and without CSS and no images.In the address bar when running my project from notepad the URL is file:///C:/wamp/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/revenant/page-about-us.php which is incorect ofcourse.Also it does not understand the php code.For example the title for about us page is

```css
<?php echo get_the_title('about-us'); ?>
```

But when I write manually in the address bar the URL of my project like localhost/wordpress everythng shows as they shown before with no problem.I have not changed any settings in notepad.Why this problem came up with no reason?Why it doesnot load php and css? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ doesn't know that you have a webserver running or what the document root is, so it cannot take you to the file's URL. When it opens the file in the browser, it is loading the file directly off the hard drive (hence the `file://`). It is not being served by the webserver that knows how to parse PHP, it is being read directly by the browser, which does not.

Comment: I think OP knows that, and I think his question is more how to get notepad++ to execute the php file from the server

Comment: @Rizier123 I was hoping to answer the question "Why doesn't it load php and css?"

Comment: exactly!execute php files from notepad like before.